# How do I use the Advanced NTFS-FS package to automount a NTFS filesystem in Linux?

Tags: linux, mount, fstab, ntfs-3g

I want to enable Advanced NTFS-3G support (permissions and users) automatically from the fstab entry.

Comment: Besides...can you please explain a little more what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have installed the Advanced NTFS-3G support... I can now modify permissions etc, but I disabled my entry for that partition in fstab at /dev/sdb8 - I want to enable it with the extra permissions support! Testing your example thanks!

Comment: If you want to automatically mount that volume with the /etc/fstab entry, make sure to have the directory where you want it to mount, e.g. /media/data, by running `sudo mkdir /media/data`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you have it already installed on your system?

If yes then you can add something like that in your /etc/fstab: `/dev/sdb1       /media/data     ntfs-3g    default      0        0`

I suggest anyway to take a look at the [Tuxera](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/) site: there you'll find ntfs-3g itself, plus useful informations.

Comment: ??? Why the downvote? That's supposed to be a working solution and an accepted answer: it would be nice to explain such a complain! :)

Comment: Serial downvoting?